# Limit Select2 to one selection per optgroup with multiple selection in version 4.0

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I have a `select` box with multiple `optgroup` like:

```
  <select id="g1" class="select"  multiple="multiple">
    <option></option>
    <optgroup label="Group 1">
      <option value="1">Title 1 A</option>
      <option value="2">Title 1 B</option>
      <option value="3">Title 1 C</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Group 2">
      <option value="4">Title 2 A</option>
      <option value="5">Title 2 B</option>
      <option value="6">Title 2 C</option>
    </optgroup>
  </select>
```

I would need to limit my selectbox to one option per optgroup, replacing the previous selected option, example:

If I select "Title 1 A" from the first optgroup and "Title 2 A" from the second optgroup, then I select "Title 1 C" from the first optgroup the result is "Title 1 C" and "Title 2 A".

I'm using Select2 v4.0.3.

I found this solution: [Limit select2 selections by group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30246868/limit-select2-selections-by-group) 
But is for Select2 v3.5.2 and it's not compatible with the new version.

Comment: Did you try to write something yourself? Add some code.

Comment: I guess this needs writing custom code, rather than `Select2` having its own option. And note that you are repeating values.

Comment: Search... Search... Search...

Comment: i found a solution for Selec2 version 3.5.2 which is not compatible with the new 4.0!

Comment: @PraveenKumar The answer you posted is working as normal multiple select box and not as select2 multiple tag box, just see the jsfiddle.

Comment: @marcopal Should I reopen this question?

Comment: @PraveenKumar Yes please! For now i solved using 4 different select boxes, but i would really need to use a unique multi-tag box!

Comment: @marcopal Not sure, but if it helps you. I have opened the question.

Comment: I think I got a solution if you still need it. I will look at it more tomorrow

Comment: @Bindrid it would be great! Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I came up with a solution that you can probably adapt.  Optgroups do not figure in but should work anyway.

HTML:

```
<select multiple style="width: 300px">
    <option groupid="a" value="A_AK">Alaska</option>
    <option groupId="b" value="B_HI">Hawaii</option>
    <option groupid="c" value="C_CA">California</option>
    <option groupid="a" value="D_NV">Nevada</option>
    <option groupid="b" value="A_OR">Oregon</option>
    <option groupid="c" value="B_WA">Washington</option>
    <option groupid="a" value="C_AZ">Arizona</option>
    <option groupid="b" value="D_CO">Colorado</option>
    <option groupid="c"value="A_ID">Idaho</option>
    <option groupid="a" value="B_MT">Montana</option>
    <option groupid="b" value="C_NE">Nebraska</option>
    <option groupid="c" value="D_NM">New Mexico</option>
    <option groupid="a" value="A_ND">North Dakota</option>
    <option groupid="b"value="B_UT">Utah</option>
    <option groupid="c" value="C_WY">Wyoming</option>
</select>
```

You will notice that I added the group id attribute. This is used to establish the relationship between the options.

JavaScript:

```
 $(function() {
    $('select').select2({
      allowClear: true,
      placeholder: "Pick a State"
    });

    //Select2 Event handler for selecting an item
    $('select').on("select2:selecting", function(evt, f, g) {
      disableSel2Group(evt, this, true);
    });

    // Select2 Event handler for unselecting an item
    $('select').on("select2:unselecting", function(evt) {
      disableSel2Group(evt, this, false);
    });
  });


  // At some point during the select2 instantation it created the 
  // data object it needs with the source select option.
  // This function, called by the events above to set the current status for the
  // group for which the selected option belongs.
  function disableSel2Group(evt, target, disabled) {
    // Found a note in the Select2 formums on how to get the item to be selected

    var selId = evt.params.args.data.id;
    var group = $("option[value='" + selId + "']").attr("groupid");

    var aaList = $("option", target);
    $.each(aaList, function(idx, item) {
      var data = $(item).data("data");

      var itemGroupId = $("option[value='" + data.id + "']").attr("groupid");
      if (itemGroupId == group && data.id != selId) {
        data.disabled = disabled;
      }
    })
  }
```

Comment: I have tried your solution to make it work in dynamic append optgroup..

please check this jsfiddle : 

https://jsfiddle.net/vijaysinh_parmar/6gr71whx/4/ 

but I am getting Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined error in deleting.. Could you please help?

Comment: I suspect that it has to do with the "Single" and "Dual" that you are appending.  Because of the way they are appended, they do not have a data object assoicated with them so a javascript error is caused when you try to access the id of an undefined object inside the loop.

Comment: I added the data object as shown here https://jsfiddle.net/2yzk0hvs/   . the error goes away but the items do not show up in the list.

Comment: yes, the error disappear, I am appending optgroup data via ajax call in success.. 

I tried to re-initialize by $('select').trigger('change'); but than also Its not visible..

Comment: $.post('/get_ajax_data/',{custom_param:1}, function(data){ var result = data.result; $("#client1_select").select2({ data:result }); $('#client1_select').trigger("change"); }); 

The code is like this one... I am getting data and its displaying as well, but its merging with existing select box.. I just wants to replace with New data.